# mysql left outer join with two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables, one with user info and one with oauth info.

I'm allowing people to have multiple oauth logins per user account - so I have an oauth table that has:

`ID|Provider|Identifier|UserID`

I can't figure out the query I would need, but I need to use this table to then find all of the user data I have with that UserID.

So If I know the provider and identifier info, I can then use the UserID on that row, to join on the rest of the data and log the user in. Do I need a left join or something similar?

Comment: Tim, can you give a before-after example and `user info` table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `left join` would return rows even if no match is found.  Since it doesn't make sense to log on someone who is not a user, an `inner join` would be more appropriate.  An `inner join` is the default type, and you can omit it:

```
select  *
from    OathLogins ol
join    Users u
on      u.ID = ol.ID
where   ol.Provider = 'Sesame Street'
        and ol.Identifier = 'Bert'
```

Comment: That is magic. Had to change your `oi` to `ol` like the rest but that's perfect. Thanks a lot @Andomar

Answer (score 0):

```
select UI.ID, UI.Provider, UI.Identifier, UI.UserID
    from  user_info UI 
    left outer join oauth_info OI on UI.ID=OI.ID

At, last put where cluase like : " where UI.ID=3 " like
```